# lost connection with neo4j after a long time

Tags: php, neo4j, rabbitmq, supervisord, neo4j-php-ogm

I am using version **Neo4j 3.5.5 (Community)** and the **graphaware / neo4j-php-client** and **graphaware / neo4j-php-ogm libraries** and everything works wonders.

I am also using **Supervisord (3.2.4)**, because I need to run a **RabbitMQ consumer (3.6.16)** using the **php-amqplib / php-amqplib** and **php-amqplib / rabbitmq-bundle** libraries.

This is my config

```
dbms.directories.import=import
dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true
dbms.connector.http.enabled=true
dbms.connector.https.enabled=true
dbms.jvm.additional=-XX:+UseG1GC
dbms.jvm.additional=-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
dbms.jvm.additional=-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch
dbms.jvm.additional=-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
dbms.jvm.additional=-XX:+TrustFinalNonStaticFields
dbms.jvm.additional=-XX:+DisableExplicitGC
dbms.jvm.additional=-Djdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true
dbms.windows_service_name=pepe
dbms.jvm.additional=-Dunsupported.dbms.udc.source=tarball
wrapper.java.additional=-Dneo4j.ext.udc.source=docker
dbms.tx_log.rotation.retention_policy=100M size
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.*
dbms.memory.pagecache.size=512M
dbms.memory.heap.max_size=512M
dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=512M
dbms.directories.logs=/logs
dbms.connectors.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0
dbms.connector.https.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7473
dbms.connector.http.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7474
dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7687
apoc.import.file.use_neo4j_config=1
apoc.import.file.enabled=1
apoc.export.file.enabled=1
HOME=/var/lib/neo4j
EDITION=community
dbms.unmanaged_extension_classes=org.neo4j.graphql=/graphql
```

RabbitMQ messages simply contain the email of the user who triggered the message to filter by that email and modify a property in my neo4j database.

When messages are received from the RabbitMQ queue, everything often works fine. But when the RabbitMQ queue passes a long time without receiving messages (1 or 2 hours) then when it receives a message the RabbitMQ queue loses the consumer and in the neo4j logs it is written:

```
2019-10-31 20: 27: 51.795 + 0000 WARN [onbtpHouseKeeper] Fatal error occurred when handling a client connection, remote peer unexpectedly closed connection: [id: 0x9b711ca5, L: /10.0.1.18: 7687 - R: /10.0 .1.77: 39560]
2019-10-31 20: 43: 09.298 + 0000 WARN [onbtpHouseKeeper] Fatal error occurred when handling a client connection, remote peer unexpectedly closed connection: [id: 0xd8522c49, L: /10.0.1.18: 7687 - R: /10.0 .1.77: 47928]
2019-10-31 20: 54: 04.658 + 0000 WARN [onbtpHouseKeeper] Fatal error occurred when handling a client connection, remote peer unexpectedly closed connection: [id: 0x27147a75, L: /10.0.1.18: 7687 - R: /10.0 .1.77: 48782]
```

Comment: This might be helpful: https://community.neo4j.com/t/fatal-error-occurred-when-handling-a-client-connection-causes-crash/9005

Comment: thanks @cybersam but that answer I don't think I know my mistake

Comment: Hi @jaime, did you find any solution for this situation ?

Comment: Hi @ugurtosun. No, I didn't.